# Hiding the first character in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an app where i want to alter the user's input string
Suppose user presses any button and i dont want to display that character in the edittext and it is just saved in variable and the characters entered afterwards are displayed.
Is there any way to hide and save the character pressed by user??

Comment: You show rather little effort. One simple google query and you wouldve known how to fix it. What have you tried, if anything at all?

Comment: I have tried input filter and also various string manipulation techniques but it did'nt worked.Only then i used google :P

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for a `TextWatcher#afterTextChanged`

Psuedo code. Be aware,

> This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text has been changed. It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this callback, but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively. (You are not told where the change took place because other afterTextChanged() methods may already have made other changes and invalidated the offsets. But if you need to know here, you can use setSpan(Object, int, int, int) in onTextChanged(CharSequence, int, int, int) to mark your place and then look up from here where the span ended up.

```
EditText searchTo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
    searchTo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           if (s.toString().contains("P")) {
              searchTo.setText(s.toString().replace("P", "W");
           }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        } 

    });
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: I have a small doubt.Will it change all occurences of 'P' with 'W' or only the first occurence??

Comment: All. Again, this is psuedo code. Adapt it to fit your needs. There are other String#replace options.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html for other options, including `replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`

Comment: I have to replace in ontextchanged method or after textchanged method??

Comment: the docs state that for onTextChanged and beforeTextChanged, `It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback.`

Comment: And as the first line of the answer states, `TextWatcher#afterTextChanged`

Comment: ... TextWatcher#afterTextChanged

Comment: i have the example in my answer, i do not see what the confusion is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextWatcher on edittext.

```
    edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //find character and replace over here
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Or, you can try `setKeyListener`

```
    edtText.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //compare keyCode and do accordingly
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getInputType() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content, int states) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    })
```

Comment: I dont want to change all occurences of 'P'.I just want to change the first character

Comment: @user3873484 you mean, first "P" or first character, whatever it is? or first character if its P?

Comment: Only first character.It can be'p','u','x' anything